# using regular expressions with java string.replace

Tags: java, regex, string

I have two questions.

1:

String = xx yy **

I want to remove "xx " so String becomes = "yy **"  (xx/yy is fixed and ** can be anything)
I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
string.replaceall("^(xx )$", "");
```

Isn't this supposed to replace the first occurence of "xx " with "" ?

SOLVED(by Lucas)

2:

String = xx yy **

I want to remove " yy **" so that String becomes = "xx"
I thought something like this, but since the first doesnt work i suspoect this will not too.

```
string.replaceall("^( yy)*$", "");
```

UNSOLVED

I actually phrased this one insufficiently,

xx should be **

so xx is not fixed

** yy **
should become ** which is the first **

Comment: You shouldn't modify your question that much, putting results from answers in your question. It will become complicated for other stackoverflow users to understand what you are asking...

Comment: Yes you are right, I deleted some of the unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the question1:

```
string.replaceFirst("^xx ", "");
```

for the second one:

```
string.replaceFirst(" yy .*$", "");
```

EDIT:
if regex is not a must, we can use this for the second one:

```
string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" yy");
```

EDIT2: If '\n' will be included in the string, this works for the second one:

```
string.replaceFirst(" yy [\\w\\W]*$", "");
```

Comment: @Tunca Ersoy: Just add two solutions for the second condition.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you're using `^` and `$` before and after what you're trying to replace. That tries to match *the whole string* with the bit that you want to remove. That's why it's not removing anything.

If you really only want to replace the *first* occurrence of `xx`, you should probably look at creating a `Pattern`, matching it against the text, and using `Matcher.replaceFirst` to perform the replacement.